# Assign struct member from loop?

Tags: c++, loops, struct

I have struct data type

```
struct column {
    int member1;
    int member2;
};
```

And I also have a loop

```
counter=1;

for(counter; counter <= input_column; counter++) {
    printf("%d", counter);  
}
```

How do I assign every loop counter to member of struct `column`?

Example : if user inputs 5, then the struct `column` members should become something like this:

```
struct column {
    int member1;
    int member2;
    int member3;
    int member4;
    int member5;
};
```

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: C++ doesn't work this way.

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to achieve - your question sounds very much like [an XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). That said, I suspect you may be looking for `std::vector<int>`

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is you can't. a struct is a type, their size, variables, and methods are know and set at compile time. However, you can use something like an array or an `std::vector<t>` to store multiple values.